Does $\,g_1/g_2=g_2/g_1\,$ imply $\,|F_1/F_2|=|F_2/F_1|\,$?
Let $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2$ be holomorphic and even functions on $\mathbb{C}$, where: 
$$
\left\lbrace\matrix{\sqrt{2}\,f_1(s)=g_1(s)+g_2(s)\cr\sqrt{2}\,f_2(s)=g_1(s)-g_2(s)}\right\rbrace\iff\left\lbrace\matrix{\sqrt{2}\,g_1(s)=f_1(s)+f_2(s)\cr\sqrt{2}\,g_2(s)=f_1(s)-f_2(s)}\right\rbrace
$$
Hence $\left\{f_1\,f_2=0 \iff g_1/g_2={\small\pm}1\right\}$ and $\left\{g_1\,g_2=0 \iff f_1/f_2={\small\pm}1\right\}$ 

Each of $f_1,f_2$ has its own reflection function around the imaginary axis: 
$F_1(s)=f_1(-s)/f_1(+s) \quad\&\quad F_2(s)=f_2(-s)/f_2(+s)$ 
Where both $F_1,F_2$ are holomorphic and non-vanishing functions on $\mathbb{C}$, 
With the modulus $|F_1(s)/F_2(s)|=1$ on the imaginary axis $\Re(s)=0$, 
And strictly increasing around it $\,\{r,r_1,r_2 \in\mathbb{R}^{+}\,\&\, r_1\lt1\lt r_2\}\,$: 
$r_1 \le |F_1(s)/F_2(s)| \le r_2 \,:\, -r \le\Re(s)\le +r\,$. 
$$
\left|\frac{F_1(s)}{F_2(s)}\right|=
\begin{cases}
r_1\,&\,:\,\Re(s)=-r \\
\,1\,&\,:\,\Re(s)=\,0 \\
r_2\,&\,:\,\Re(s)=+r
\end{cases}
$$

How to prove (or disprove) the symmetric flipping effect of:
$$ \frac{g_1(s)}{g_2(s)}=\frac{g_2(s)}{g_1(s)}\,\implies\,\left|\frac{F_1(s)}{F_2(s)}\right|=\left|\frac{F_2(s)}{F_1(s)}\right| $$

Obviously, the system is fully symmetric, has a Cayley/Mobius like transformations, and could be written in various ways closer to Schwarz lemma. Appreciating your help, Thanks.

General Ideas (NOT Answers)
$\displaystyle{\bf{\space\text{1.}\space\space\frac{F_1(s)/F_2(s)-1}{F_1(s)/F_2(s)+1}\space\colon\space}}$ 
$$
\begin{align}
\,&\frac{F_1(s)}{F_2(s)}=\frac{f_1({\small+}s)f_2({\small-}s)}{f_2({\small+}s)f_1({\small-}s)} \\ 
\,&Z\mapsto\frac{Z-1}{Z+1} \\ 
\,&\frac{f_1({\small+}s)f_2({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}-}\,f_2({\small+}s)f_1({\small-}s)}{f_1({\small+}s)f_2({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}+}\,f_2({\small+}s)f_1({\small-}s)} = -\frac{g_1({\small+}s)g_2({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}-}\,g_2({\small+}s)g_1({\small-}s)}{g_1({\small+}s)g_1({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}-}\,g_2({\small+}s)g_2({\small-}s)} 
&\end{align}
$$
If this function is pure imaginary at $\,g_1/g_2={\small\pm}1\,$ then $\,|F_1/F_2|=1\,$. 


$\displaystyle{\bf{\space\text{2.}\space\space\frac{H(s_1)-\overline{H(s_2)}}{H(s_1)\,\overline{H(s_2)}-1}\space\colon\space}}$ 
$$
\begin{align}
\,&\left|\frac{F_1(s)}{F_2(s)}\right| = \left|\frac{f_1({\small+}s)f_2({\small-}\overline{s})}{f_2({\small+}s)f_1({\small-}\overline{s})}\right| \\ 
\,&\frac{f_1({\small+}s)f_2({\small-}\overline{s})\,{\color{red}-}\,f_2({\small+}s)f_1({\small-}\overline{s})}{f_1({\small+}s)f_2({\small-}\overline{s})\,{\color{red}+}\,f_2({\small+}s)f_1({\small-}\overline{s})} = -\frac{{g_1({\small+}s)\,/\,g_2({\small+}s)}\,{\color{red}-}\,\overline{g_1({\small-}s)\,/\,g_2({\small-}s)}}{{g_1({\small+}s)}/{g_2({\small+}s)}\,\overline{g_1({\small-}s)/g_2({\small-}s)}\,{\color{red}-}\,1} 
\end{align}
$$
If this function is pure imaginary at $\,g_1/g_2={\small\pm}1\,$ then $\,|F_1/F_2|=1\,$. 


$\displaystyle{\bf{\space\text{3.}\space\space\left(Z_1,Z_2\right)\mapsto\frac{Z_1-1}{Z_1+1}\,\frac{Z_2+1}{Z_2-1}\space\colon\space}}$ 
$$
\begin{align}
\,&+\frac{f_1({\small+}s)f_2({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}-}\,f_2({\small+}s)f_1({\small-}s)}{f_1({\small+}s)f_2({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}+}\,f_2({\small+}s)f_1({\small-}s)}\,\,
\frac{f_1({\small+}s)f_1({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}+}\,f_2({\small+}s)f_2({\small-}s)}{f_1({\small+}s)f_1({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}-}\,f_2({\small+}s)f_2({\small-}s)}= \\ 
\,&-\frac{g_1({\small+}s)g_2({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}-}\,g_2({\small+}s)g_1({\small-}s)}{g_1({\small+}s)g_2({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}+}\,g_2({\small+}s)g_1({\small-}s)}\,\,
\frac{g_1({\small+}s)g_1({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}+}\,g_2({\small+}s)g_2({\small-}s)}{g_1({\small+}s)g_1({\small-}s)\,{\color{red}-}\,g_2({\small+}s)g_2({\small-}s)} 
\end{align}
$$
Appling this transform for either $\{f_1,f_2\}$ or $\{g_1,g_2\}$ result on equality. 

You allow $f_1(s) = 0$ and/or $f_2(s) = 0$ when you write $f_1 , f_2 = 0$.  Why do you believe $F_1$ and $F_2$ are non-vanishing?

@EricTowers, ${F_1,&,F_2,\ne0}$ is a given property of these two functions (i.e.$,\cosh$). This is equivalent to say that the limit ${\lim_{s\rightarrow s_x},f_1(-s)/f_1(+s)=F_1(s_x)}$ dos exist and doesn't equal $0$, where $f_1(-s_x)=f_1(+s_x)=0,$. (similarly goes for $F_2$)

In the question "holomorphic and even" means: $f(s)=\overline{f(\overline{s})}$
